# i need to echo a dropdown selection which is populated from mysql on another page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have a three drop downs, 2 of which are populated from Mysql, so depending on what is selected in the first, define's what populates in the second, and then third. however. i need to take the users 3 selections, and carry them onto the next page and echo them, and then the same for the third page, i need to take the first pages answers, and the second, and echo them on the third page. and so on. this is my code so far:

```
<?php
``if (@$_REQUEST['ajax']) {
// connect to local database 'test' on localhost
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if ($link == false)
    trigger_error('Connect failed - ' . mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);

$connected = mysql_select_db('test', $link);

if ($connected) {
    $results = mysql_query('select * from test.select_chain where category="' . strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_REQUEST['category']))) . '"');

    $json = array();

    while (is_resource($results) && $row = mysql_fetch_object($results)) {
        //$json[] = '{"id" : "' . $row->id . '", "label" : "' . $row->label . '"}';
        $json[] = '"' . $row->label . '"';
    }

    echo '[' . implode(',', $json) . ']';
    die(); // filthy exit, but does fine for our example.
} else {
    user_error("Failed to select the database");
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Select Chain</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
<!--
  BODY { margin: 10px; padding: 0; font: 1em "Trebuchet MS", verdana, arial, sans-serif; }
  BODY { font-size: 100%; }
  H1 { margin-bottom: 2px; font-family: Garamond, "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;}
  DIV.selHolder { float: left; border: 3px solid #ccc; margin: 10px; padding: 5px;}
  TEXTAREA { width: 80%;}
  FIELDSET { border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 1em; margin: 0; }
  LEGEND { color: #ccc; font-size: 120%; }
  INPUT, TEXTAREA { font-family: Arial, verdana; font-size: 125%; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid #999; }
  LABEL { display: block; margin-top: 10px; } 
  IMG { margin: 5px; }
  SELECT { margin: 10px; width: 200px; }
-->
</style>

<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="select-chain.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(function () {
    var cat = $('#categorySelect');
    var el = $('#elementSelect');
    var attr = $('#attributeSelect');

    el.selectChain({
        target: attr,
        url: 'index.php',
        data: { ajax: true, anotherval: "anotherAction" }            
    });        

    // note that we're assigning in reverse order
    // to allow the chaining change trigger to work
    cat.selectChain({
        target: el,
        url: 'index.php',
        data: { ajax: true }
    }).trigger('change');

});
//-->
   </script>
  </head>
    <center><img src="tgd.png" alt="The Global Dollar" href="index.php"></center>
   <body id="page">
    <div id="doc">
    <center><h1>Country</h1></center>
    <div class="selHolder">
        <h2>Continent</h2>
        <select id="categorySelect" name="category" size="5">
          <option>Africa</option>
      <option>America</option>
  <option>Antarctica</option>
  <option>Asia</option>
  <option>Australia</option>
  <option>Europe</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="selHolder">
        <h2>Country</h2>
        <select id="elementSelect" name="category" size="5">
            <option>[none selected]</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="selHolder">
        <h2>City</h2>
        <select id="attributeSelect" name="category" size="5">
            <option>[none selected]</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>
   <a href="../secondpage">Next Page </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Anyone know how i can do this? sorry if i have been unclear, its hard to describe. 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways a web client can pass information to the next page loaded:

- Put the information in the URL's query string (basically what happens when you submit a form via GET). The next page can parse the query string.
- Send the information to the server as POST data when the user goes to the next page. The server can write the information into the next page as it's delivered.
- You can build upon the prior idea by storing the information with [PHP sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php). That would let the server remember the user's selections for a period of time even if the user leaves the page and comes back.
- You could store the information in cookies. Cookies can be set and read entirely with JavaScript if you want.
- HTML5 local storage is probably overkill, but if you're going to end up building something complex....

Comment: Its going to be really complex, id like to use either either of the last 3, can you explain any of them for me? im not a hugely experienced programmer? thank you so far!

Comment: I suggest reading through PHP's sessions documentation. It lets you easily store data for a user's interaction with the server without having to write a ton of code. As the intro page says: The session support allows you to store data between requests in the $_SESSION superglobal array. When a visitor accesses your site, PHP will check automatically ... or on your request ... whether a specific session id has been sent with the request. If this is the case, the prior saved environment is recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about Dynamic Dropdown functionality here. And going by fetching the options from MySQL, I found a source for you.

May be you can refer this and sort it out.

[Dynamic Dropdown Powered by MySQL](http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-dropdowns/)